# Laravel package development how do I use another facade in my package

Tags: php, laravel, templates, view, facade

I am creating my own Laravel package, in my package I have some views and I want to use the `Form` facade in one of my views, something like this: `Form::open()`. Is this possible, if so, how?

This is my `composer.json`:

`{
    "name": "thomasbird/laravel-cms",
    "description": "A basic content management package that encapsulates some of the common functionality of a cms",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Thomas Bird",
            "email": "godoploid@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "^3.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify any required packages within the `require` section of your composer.json.

For example, if you wish to use laravel collective's html helpers, in your package's `composer.json`, you can specify as follows:

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.0",
        "laravelcollective/html":"^5.4.0",
        ...
        ...
        ...
```

So you can  use any facades included within your required packages.

Comment: Thank you @PSJ, I added my `composer.json` to the question. I ran a `composer install` to install the dependency, then a `composer dump-autoload` but I still get the error `class Form not found`